# Open xls (xml) using Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, xls

Im trying opening a xls file with python and it's not working.
I get error message:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<?xml ve'
```

I think the file is a xml but the extension is xls and I can open it normally using excel.

My code:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/frsiq/Downloads/ca.xls')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Nº da solicitação','Data de início'])
print (df)
```